# What is the equation of a tangent line on a circle with angle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I have been given a task to write [head up display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-up_display) screen for the drone we are working on.
The work has come up to the showing the roll degrees, which the mathematical form of the problem is as below:

> **Problem:** Let's say we have a circle with the equation of $(x - c_0)^2 + (y-c_1)^2 = r$. What is the equation of tangent line touches the circle at $\theta$ degree?
>   [image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Parametric representation of the tangent**

As vector $\vec{T}:=\binom{r \sin(\theta)}{-r \cos(\theta)}$ is orthogonal to $\vec{OP}$ (their dot product is $0$), we can write that a general point $M=\binom{x}{y}$ belonging to the tangent line is such that $\vec{PM}=t\vec{T} \ \Leftrightarrow \ M=P+t\vec{T}$, otherwise said, because $P=\binom{c_0+r \cos(\theta)}{c_1+r \sin(\theta)}$:

$$\begin{cases}x(t)&=&c_0+r \cos(\theta)+tr\sin(\theta)\\y(t)&=&c_1+r \sin(\theta)-t r \cos(\theta)\end{cases}$$

If we desire for example the coordinates of point $F$, it suffices to find the values of $t$ to which it is associated. It is such that the $y$ oridnate is $0$, giving $t=t_M=\frac{c_1+r \sin(\theta)}{r \cos(\theta)}.$

2) **Cartesian equation of the tangent**

For this issue and other issues of the same type, here is a more general result :

The tangent line in $(x_0,y_0)$ to a conic (circle, ellipse, parabola, hyperbola) with equation:

$$\tag{1}ax^2+by^2+2cxy+2dx+2ey+f=0$$

is

$$\tag{2}axx_0+byy_0+c(xy_0+x_0y)+d(x+x_0)+e(y+y_0)+f=0$$

It suffices for you to apply (2) in the case of the conic with equation: $$(x - c_0)^2 + (y-c_1)^2 = r^2  \Longleftrightarrow x^2 + y^2 -2 c_0x -2 c_1y + (c_0^2+c_1^2-r^2)=0 \ \text{at point}$$

$$(x_0,y_0)=(c_0+r \cos(\theta),c_1+r \sin(\theta)).$$

There remains a last computation. Up to you...

Comment: I have added another solution, more simple but specific to circles (point 1), the earlier one being now point 2.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

the slope of tangent is
$$y'=-\frac{1}{\tan\theta}$$